# Best way to deploy changes for multiple databases using liquibase

Tags: liquibase, changelog

Newbie to liquibase here. We have a requirement to deploy same changes to multiple databases in amazon RDS.

1. What will be the best way to deploy? Using different change logs for different databases and include them in one master changeLog or using a single changeLog file and use context tag in changeSet? I read couple other articles but not able to find a concrete solution.
2. And also we have .dll files to deploy. Do we convert them to .sql and then use  tag or is there any tags for .dll files?

Note: we are not using any java/maven application.

Answer (score 0):

the answer for your post depends on what type of deployment you are doing. There could be a simple pipeline where you want the same changes made to the different databases, or subset of changes on different pipeline database (eg dev, test, prod)

Liquibase do not work on .dll file (binary or complied files). Liquibase works only for text based files (sql, json, yaml and xml). You can read more on it [here](https://docs.liquibase.com/concepts/basic/changelog.html)

Comment: we want to deploy same changes to different databases eg dev,test,prod